# How to define gradle project as library dependency in Play?

Tags: maven, gradle, sbt

I have a project, which is written using the Play Framework, say `myproject-web`. It is mostly a thin HTTP layer over another project, which forms the core of the entire business logic, called `myproject-engine`. In my build setup, `myproject-web` is a sbt project, whereas `myproject-engine` is a Gradle one.

What I want to achieve is that Play recognize `myproject-engine` as a dependency, and invoke gradle to build it whenever I try to build the play application (either on `run`, or automatically, as it happens in the dev mode) or when I do `play dist`. Is it possible? What is most important for me is that it automatically loads any dependencies that `myproject-engine` has.

Eventually, the state I want it to reach is that I host my Maven repo for these projects and then SBT can simply pull this package from over there and will get all its dependencies. Is this rather easy to setup? Even if it is, is it relatively easy to maintain?

Comment: Exchanging dependencies via a local or remote binary repository is the most sensible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Peter-Niederwieser pointed out in his comment, I think the only viable solution is to have a maven/ivy/gradle repository where the `myproject-engine` Gradle project is published to. With the correct `resolvers` the project becomes yet another project dependency, regardless of the build tool it uses.

See [Resolvers](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Resolvers.html) in the official documentation of sbt.